# How to Insert Large Amount of Varbinary(max) Rows Into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I use a local SQL Server. I have table with 250k of photos (`DropPhotos`). Photos are stored in a `Varbinary(max)` column which is called `Content`. I want to move all of this rows into another table within same database (`BasePhotos`) along with some additional columns. I wrote SQL statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.BasePhotos (PhotoId, Name, Content, AddedDate, CreationDateTime, PhotoType)
    SELECT PhotoId, Name, Content, AddedDate, CreationDateTime, PhotoType
    FROM dbo.DropPhotos
```

When I start execution everything goes normal. After several minutes (5 - 15 mins) my screen starts to turn on and off randomly, then it turns off and after several more minutes my pc goes into reboot. I suspect that moving so much binary data drains all of it RAM and leads to shutdown.  I've searched online for solution and discovered that there is exist some kind of Bulk Insert. Maybe it could help me? But as far as I know it is used to insert rows from file, not from one table from another.

So my question is quite simple: How to approach inserting large amount of heavy rows into table.

**PhotoId is uniqueidentifier**

Comment: Try to run `INSERT INTO` in a loop where you insert e.g. 100 records in each insert. BR

Comment: Consider breaking this up over several batches

Comment: Depending on your hardware, using `tablock` hint can also help

Comment: @Stu: I believe `tablock` will cause a table lock, and that may give some unwanted side-effects in an app. My experience is that logging during large inserts is the main issue, hence small batches is the way to go. BR

Comment: @RoarS. No, the OP is insertinto *into* a new table; using a `tablock` hint will allow SQL Server to exclusively lock this table and allow a parallel plan, this can significantly speed up inserts. Making sure the table inserting into is also a *heap* will help if it isn't already.

Comment: @Stu: I can't see anything in the question that indicates that `BasePhotos` is recreated, but I'll take your word for it. BR

Comment: I somehow assumed it was a new table - so it's going to be an "it depends" scenario for the OP; inserting with the `tablock` hint will lock the table for the duration, but potentially allow faster insert. If concurrency is required then doing so in conjunction with small batches of inserts could be the best fit. Although with the description of the issue, it sounds like this is on a local desktop PC so probably not an issue.

Comment: Does not sound like running out of RAM to me - it sounds like the computer is overheating. Ensure the cooling works properly, use tools to monitor the CPU temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Please note that OP is asking for moving records in the question, this was later changed to copying records in a comment.

The batch approach discussed above, may be implemented like this:

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @IdTable TABLE (id uniqueidentifier)

insert into @IdTable(id) 
    select top 100 
        dropPhotos.PhotoId 
    from 
        dbo.DropPhotos dropPhotos
        left join dbo.BasePhotos basePhotos on dropPhotos.PhotoId = basePhotos.PhotoId
    where
        basePhotos.PhotoId is null

while exists(select top 1 1 from @IdTable)
begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.BasePhotos (PhotoId, Name, Content, AddedDate, CreationDateTime, PhotoType)
        SELECT PhotoId, Name, Content, AddedDate, CreationDateTime, PhotoType
        FROM dbo.DropPhotos
        WHERE PhotoId IN (select id from @IdTable)

    delete from @IdTable

    insert into @IdTable(id) 
        select top 100 
            dropPhotos.PhotoId 
        from 
           dbo.DropPhotos dropPhotos
           left join dbo.BasePhotos basePhotos on dropPhotos.PhotoId = basePhotos.PhotoId
        where
            basePhotos.PhotoId is null
end
```

Comment: Actually PhotoId is uniqueidentifier, sorry that I havent mentioned it in question

Comment: @Fallingsappy: Updated my answer with uniqueidentifier and `set nocount on`

Comment: If I understand correctly this query will delete records from original table which is not desired behaviour

Comment: @Fallingsappy: Removed delete DropPhotos from my answer. BR

Comment: @Fallingsappy But you did write "I want to move all of this rows" which implies deleting the original rows.